# py2app not including pythonpath

Tags: python, py2app

I'm trying to build an app with py2app. I can build the app but when I run it I get `ImportError` in the console, the import error is that there is `No module named PythonApp` which is the folder all my source is in, the location of which is in my `PYTHONPATH`.

I have been importing local files like `from PythonApp import file` instead of just `import file` to help avoid namespace issues.

I have tried to build it with the following flag `python setup.py py2app --use-pythonpath` but this hasn't appeared to make any difference.

- Should I just change the import statements throughout to `import file`?
- How can I make py2app realise my `PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem well, you have the following layout:

```
PythonApp/
  __init__.py
  file.py
  foo.py
```

And you try to import the module `file` from `foo.py` by `from PythonApp import file`. If this the only reason you want to set `PYTHONPATH`, there is a simpler solution: use [relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/):

```
from . import file
```

You can use `from .. import file` in a sub-package of `PythonApp`, and so on. This way you can avoid name collisions with standard modules.

If you need to hack the import path for some other reasons, you can also set the `sys.path` variable in the startup script (probably py2app has some options for that, too). Keep in mind though that if you add external directories into the import path, it will be harder to distribute the app bundle.

Also, a more trivial explanation for the `ImportError` is that py2app did not copy your package into the app bundle. Make sure you have all your packages listed in the `packages` parameter of `setup()`.